# Jquery Validation in C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a website using C# MVC and i have to use jquery in it.. the thing is on the index page of the website there is a textfield where user has to enter a registration number.. i have to check whether the textfield is empty or not.. if the textfield is empty a message should be shown to the user telling him that field is empty.. i have done this thing but when the user presses enter the form gets submitted due to which i get null in my controller as the registration number user enters goes to an api which brings some data back..this is what i have done so far.. and i dont want the form to get submit when the textfield is empty.. what i am missing here as i am new to jquery.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#no_reg_num').hide();

        $('#reg_num_form').submit(function () {
            var reg_num = $('#reg_num').val();
            if (reg_num == null || reg_num == "")
            {
                $('#no_reg_num').show();

            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: add return false into the submit function to stop the submit

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false;` when the text field is empty to prevent submitting the form

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#no_reg_num').hide();

        $('#reg_num_form').submit(function () {
            var reg_num = $('#reg_num').val();
            if (reg_num == null || reg_num == "")
            {
                $('#no_reg_num').show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```